# Database Exception with Gii Generator on Yii2

Tags: php, oracle, yii, gii

First of all, my details(I try to include as much as I can):

PHP 5.6.14

Oracle DB11G Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0(Installed locally, default localhost setup)

Windows 7 64-Bit

Oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86

Yii 2.0.6

I am trying to use the gii module to generate some models for testing purpose(as I am fairly new to this framework). I have imported all the tables/data from my organization's database, and have create related tablespaces and users. So my generator have these autocompleted when i typed partial keywords.

[image]

Then when I clicked on preview button, i get this error below

[image]

I believe the SYSTEM/SYSAUX are generated automatically when installing the oracle db. Plus, the autocomplete tables that appeared when I try to insert the table name is correct and same as the tables i have inside our schema. I tried changing the password/creds to be wrong as I cant access the gii page at all(so i believe the connection to my db setup is fine).

Can anyone help me. is it a known issue or i am doing something wrong? because as far as I understand, the error shown means that the generator is looking at a different place upon clicking the "preview" button.

Thank you.

**

### UPDATE: New error

**

I gave the current user the role of DBA and now it's getting somewhere but I do not understand the cause/errors.

[image]

Comment: One issue could be that the user which is executing the query doesn't have the **DBA** privilege to access `dba_users` and `dba_objects`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Getting somewhere. please see my updated post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Looking at the failing SQL, it seems the user which is executing the query doesn't have the **DBA** privilege to access `dba_users` and `dba_objects`. You need to **GRANT** the required privilege to this user.

```
GRANT DBA to new_user;
```

Comment: I did, see the updated post up there. Just below the original post. the PHP NOTICE screenshot.

Comment: @Luqman I am afraid I won't b able to help with `php`. But I ccan help with Oracle database. The first issue was with the `DBA` privilege, it's fixed now. Looking ta your update, I can say that at line 511, `$relations[$table-->fullname][$name]`. you are trying to access something as an **object**, which is not an **object**.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out. Since my databases and tables are pretty huge, I need to uncheck the "Generate with relations" checkbox.

Everything is now working fine. I am now able to fully utilize the Gii goodness!

Anyway I still chose Lalit Kumar's answer since that really helps a lot as it is something that I can't even imagine, thinking it was not something related to the DB. Turns out it is!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback +1. Should help others.

Answer (score 0):

the second error about relations generation is a bug about Yii2, and now have been fixed.

Ref:
Fixes #166: Fixed "Trying to get property of non-object" during model…

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/commit/45696e9f01485799022b0daa56372fc00baece06